# C Shell: different actions depending on the file type

Tags: filenames, csh, patterns

I very new to C Shell. I am trying to read a file from the command line, and determine whether it's a zip file, a .txt, a symbloic link, a pipe, or whatever ("unknown").

Then I'd like to execute a few instructions depending on the type. For instance, if it's a txt file, print information about it ("it's a text file") and give its size.

Here is what I what got so far:

```
!/bin/csh

if ( "echo ${1} | cut -d'.' -f2" == "zip" ) then
    echo $1 is a zip file
else
    echo sorry, $1 is not a zip file
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `switch` to analyze the file name.

```
switch ($1)
case *.zip:
  echo "$1 is a zip file"
  breaksw
default:
  echo "${1}: not supported"
endsw
```

To analyze the file type, parse the output of `ls`: the first character is the file type.

```
switch ("`ls -logd "$1"`")
case d*:
  echo "$1 is a directory"
  breaksw
# ...
endsw
```

In fact you're probably looking for the [`file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) command, which analyzes the file's content to determine what format of data it contains (and reports the file type for non-regular files).

```
file -- "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks to evaluate to the result of the command inside, this is the same as other shells.  So, instead of

```
"echo ${1} | cut -d'.' -f2"
```

which is a string that most certainly does not equal the string "zip", use

```
`echo ${1} | cut -d'.' -f2`
```

which evaluates the command inside and returns the result.